# How to convert and compare NSNumber to BOOL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

First I convert BOOL value to NSNumber in order to put it into NSUserDefaults. Later I would like to retrieve the BOOL value from the NSUserDefaults, but obviously I get NSNumber instead of BOOL. My questions are?

1. how to convert back from NSNumber to BOOL?
2. How to compare NSNumber to BOOL value.

Currently I have:

```
if (someNSNumberValue == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]) {
    do something
}
```

any better way to to the comparison?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, just maybe read the [spec for NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)??

Comment: @HotLicks I understand your exasperation with excessively simple and unresearched questions. But for those of us experienced with more modern languages that offer a real Boolean data type, the simulation of a boolean in C and Objective-C is quite confusing – far from simple.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You currently compare two pointers. Use `NSNumber`s methods instead to actually compare the two:

```
if([someNSNumberValue isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]) {
    // ...
}
```

To get the bool value from a `NSNumber` use `-(BOOL)boolValue`:

```
BOOL b = [num boolValue];
```

With that the comparison would be easier to read for me this way:

```
if([num boolValue] == NO) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche I suggest you move the second snipped above the first one and recommend its use primarily. The first one is "less efficient" - I don't want to do premature optimization here, but why create a superfluous `NSNumber` instance?

Comment: @H2CO3: Take a look at the original snippet from the OP, which i responded to first, to get to a better option from there.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4:**

```
let newBoolValue = nsNumberValue.boolValue
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` has two methods to transparently operate with booleans:

`- (BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)defaultName`

`- (void)setBool:(BOOL)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName`

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way I managed to finagle a `NSNumber`'s "booleanity" from its `NSConcreteValue`*(doh!)* was with the following...

```
id x = [self valueForKey:@"aBoolMaybe"];
if ([x respondsToSelector:@selector(boolValue)] && 
    [x isKindOfClass:objc_getClass("__NSCFNumber")])
    [self doSomethingThatExpectsABool:[x boolValue]];
```

Every other trick... **FAILED**.  Buyer beware, this isn't foolproof (`__NSCFNumber` may well be platform/machine specific - it is *solely Apple's implementation detail*)... but as they say.. *nothing else worked!*